# Breakline when requesting data from metrics website using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, kubernetes

I'm making a proxy that collect metrics using Python3 Flask

My example code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/metrics')
def metrics():
   x = requests.get('http://192.168.122.227:31805/metrics')
   y = requests.get('http://10.5.69.76:32303/metrics')
   
   a = (x.text)+(y.text)
   print (type(a))
   return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port="5000", debug=False)
```

The metrics site have metrics like this:

```
# HELP kube_certificatesigningrequest_labels Kubernetes labels converted to Prometheus labels.
# TYPE kube_certificatesigningrequest_labels gauge
# HELP kube_certificatesigningrequest_created Unix creation timestamp
# TYPE kube_certificatesigningrequest_created gauge
# HELP kube_certificatesigningrequest_condition The number of each certificatesigningrequest condition
# TYPE kube_certificatesigningrequest_condition gauge
# HELP kube_certificatesigningrequest_cert_length Length of the issued cert
# TYPE kube_certificatesigningrequest_cert_length gauge
# HELP kube_configmap_info Information about configmap.
...
...
```

But my proxy display like this:

```
# HELP kube_certificatesigningrequest_labels Kubernetes labels converted to Prometheus labels. # TYPE kube_certificatesigningrequest_labels gauge # HELP kube_certificatesigningrequest_created Unix creation timestamp # TYPE kube_certificatesigningrequest_created gauge # HELP kube_certificatesigningrequest_condition The number of each certificatesigningrequest condition # TYPE kube_certificatesigningrequest_condition gauge # HELP kube_certificatesigningrequest_cert_length Length of the issued cert # TYPE kube_certificatesigningrequest_cert_length gauge # HELP kube_configmap_info Information about configmap. # TYPE
...
```

So how can I breakdown line in my website, It's collect entire string so I can't seperate them.

Comment: Your flask app is returning non HTML content. So on browser, it will have no formatting. But on command line, it will look fine with proper line break. If you want to have proper formatting on browser try enclosing the content in `<pre></pre>` HTML tags like this: `a = '<pre>' + (x.text) + (y.text) + '</pre>'`.